# How to know if a request is fulfilled on python?

Tags: python

I making a request to download some data on python from Copernicus website. The thing is that I want to know when the request is fulfilled and when the download is finished.

Is is solid enough to work with 2 flags(request_finished and download_finished)?

```py
import cdsapi

c = cdsapi.Client()

latitude = 43.1 # North, South
longitude = -1.5 # West , East
    #str(latitude)+'/'+str(longitude)+'/'+str(latitude)+'/'+str(longitude)
r = c.retrieve(
        'reanalysis-era5-single-levels',
        {
            'product_type':'reanalysis',
            'variable':[
                '100m_u_component_of_wind','100m_v_component_of_wind','10m_u_component_of_wind','10m_v_component_of_wind','2m_temperature',
                'surface_pressure'
            ],
            'area'    : str(latitude)+'/'+str(longitude)+'/'+str(latitude)+'/'+str(longitude), # North, West, South, East. Default: global
            'year':'2018',
            'grid':'0.1/0.1', # Latitude/longitude grid in degrees: east-west (longitude) and north-south resolution (latitude). Default: reduced Gaussian grid
            'month':'01',
            'day':[
                '01','02','03',
                '04','05','06',
                '07','08','09',
                '10','11','12',
                '13','14','15',
                '16','17','18',
                '19','20','21',
                '22','23','24',
                '25','26','27',
                '28','29','30',
                '31'
            ],
            'time':[
                '00:00','01:00','02:00',
                '03:00','04:00','05:00',
                '06:00','07:00','08:00',
                '09:00','10:00','11:00',
                '12:00','13:00','14:00',
                '15:00','16:00','17:00',
                '18:00','19:00','20:00',
                '21:00','22:00','23:00'
            ],
            'format':'netcdf'
        }
        )
request_finished = 1

r.download('download_grid_reduction_one_month_point_limit.nc')
download_finished = 1
```

Comment: I assume that these two methods are blocking, so why do you need a flag? If it's got to that point in the code, you know the download is finished anyway

Comment: What do the `cdsapi` docs say? Do the maintainers have a way to ask them questions- you can't even get to the homepage without logging in.